# permanent fix for gtk-window-decorator --replace

Tags: gtk, gtk-windows

I've had to use this command lately to get the minimize/maximize/close buttons to show. Anyone know a permanent fix for this? (any packages I need to reinstall etc)

Edit : I'm using ubuntu 11.04 (not using Unity)

Comment: It would help if you told people what window manager or desktop environment you are using and possibly what OS.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the "Window Decorations" plugin is enabled in [CCSM](http://wiki.compiz.org/CCSM) and that it is configured to use `gtk-window-decorator`.